# ASP Label inside a panel not displaying user input

Tags: c#, label, panel

I have a label inside a table inside a panel.

Edit and Save is working properly but when I try to display them, the label is not showing the data? :/

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblfullname" runat="server" 
                            Text="Label" Visible="False" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
```

This is the code behind

```
public void DisplayProfile()
{
       this.SetElementsForDisplaying();
        lblfullname.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName;                     
}
void SetElementsForDisplaying() 
{ 
//pnlStart.Visible = false; 
pnlDisplayValues.Visible = true; 
pnlSetValues.Visible = false; 
litUserTitle.Visible = true; 
litUserTitle.Text = string.Format("Display profile for {0}", this.Profile.UserName);   
lblfullname.Visible = true; 
}
```

Comment: Hmmm `Visible="False` is this toggled ? ?

Comment: You have the visible state of the label to FALSE, set it to true in the code.

Comment: Yes. It is set to true in

     `private void SetElementsForDisplaying()
        {
            
            //pnlStart.Visible = false;
            pnlDisplayValues.Visible = true;
            pnlSetValues.Visible = false; 
            litUserTitle.Visible = true;
            litUserTitle.Text = string.Format("Display profile for {0}", this.Profile.UserName);
            lblfullname.Visible = true;
           
            
        }`

Comment: `EnableViewState="True"` should help....\

Comment: We can't look into `SetElementsForDisplaying`, also, are you initializing the `Labels` Text proeprty somewhere else(e.g. in `Page_Load`)? From where and when do you call `DisplayProfile`?

Comment: No. No label-related thing in `Page_Load`

Comment: @harag & @rapsalands

Didn't work. I actually found something when googling and it is recommended that the `viewstate` is set to `false`

Comment: For Viewstate there is no preference. It all depends on requirement.

Comment: Update: Now it literally displays 'Label'

Comment: It looks like the "DisplayProfile()" method isn't being called. Where is this called from - Page_Load?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DisplayProfile()
{

   this.SetElementsForDisplaying();
   lblfullname.Visible=true;
   lblfullname.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName;




}
```